# objective-C AVPlayer from URL

Tags: objective-c, xcode, avplayer

I'm trying to play a .mp3 from a url on an AVPlayer.

```
url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/jcq74691pet09d9/Chumbawamba%20-%20Tubthumping%20HD.mp3?dl=0"];

AVPlayerItem *item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithURL:url];
AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithPlayerItem:item];


[player play];
```

I've already imported the `AVFoundation.h` and `AVFoundation.m` and the url link also works as a direct/hot link.

Can't get it to work and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

```
// *** create AVAsset using URL ***
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/jcq74691pet09d9/Chumbawamba%20-%20Tubthumping%20HD.mp3?dl=0"]];

// *** Create AVPlayerItem using AVAsset ***
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];

// *** Initialise AVPlayer ***
avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

// *** Add AVPlayer to ViewController ***
AVPlayerLayer *avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];
avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[avPlayerLayer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor].CGColor];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];

// *** Start Playback ***
[avPlayer play];

// *** Register for playback end notification ***
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[avPlayer currentItem]];

// *** Register observer for events of AVPlayer status ***
[avPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
```

Add following Observer method to observe playback status of AVPlayer

```
// *** Observe status event and perform actions ***
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if (object == avPlayer && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (avPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Failed");

        } else if (avPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay");
            [avPlayer play];


        } else if (avPlayer.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Unknown");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
  NSURL *myurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/jcq74691pet09d9/Chumbawamba%20-%20Tubthumping%20HD.mp3?dl=0"];
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myurl];
  audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data  error:NULL];
  audioPlayer.delegate = self;
  [audioPlayer play];
```

you can write Delegate method also:

```
 -(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
    [audioPlayer stop];
     NSLog(@"Finished Playing");
  }

 - (void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioPlayer *)player error:(NSError *)error
 {
  NSLog(@"Something wrong");
 }
```